# Novel about a boy who went to a fantasy world

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I'm trying to find a book (or series?) I vaguely remember reading in a school library, somewhere between 1995 and 1998. Its target audience would have been about 8-14 year old boys.

It was a stereotypical fantasy story for kids, about a boy who I think got teleported to a fantasy world from our world. I think he gets a magic sword and goes on a typical 'epic journey' around the place to beat the bad guy. There was a girl (princess(?)) involved and they are on a boat or raft together at some point.

This boat/raft may have been on the cover, as I remember a picture of it. It had a single sail and was small.

Comment: I have voted to close this as too broad because at the moment this is likely to match way too many books. If you do remember anything else that could help narrow this down please edit it in.

Comment: I have some ideas, but it is a little bit too generic of a plotline for me to identify.

Comment: if you are able to list some out, i'll know it immediately if i can google its cover

Comment: @David can you describe its cover?